# I have an error: NameError: name 'GameDisplay' is not defined

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a game in pycharm using python and I have a name which isn't defined. I looked for information about how to fix this and the best fix I could find was changing the name from gameDisplay to GameDisplay in line 16 but it didn't help at all.  Below is the full error message I received
.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Zack's PC/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/main1.py", line 30, in <module>
    car(x,y)
  File "C:/Users/Zack's PC/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/main1.py", line 16, in car
    GameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y))
NameError: name 'GameDisplay' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

this is the file:

```
  ***import pygame
pygame.init()

display_width= 900
display_height=600
black= (0,0,0)
white= (255,255,255)
red= (255,0,0)


screen= pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Race Car')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
carImg = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/Zack\'s PC/Pictures/gameimages/racecarimage.png')
def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg,(x,y)) 


x = (display_height * 0.45)
y = (display_width * 0.8)

crashed = False

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True


    car(x,y)
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()***
```

Comment: You have to define names in your code. What do you think the name `gameDisplay` refers to?

Comment: Shouldn't gameDisplay refer to screen or background (with `background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())`)?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas my apologies I welt ahead and edited the post so now it has the full error message.

Comment: you already have answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you didn't create

```
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode(...)
```

but

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(...)
```

and now you have to use `screen` instead of `gameDisplay`

```
screen.blit(...)

screen.fill(white)
```

---

Or you have to use

```
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode(...)
```

instead of

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(...)
```